# Possible inconsistence data in db-sync

Tags: cardano-db-sync

I've this query on Preprod:

```
SELECT
    ENCODE(TX.HASH, 'hex') as tx_hash,
    TX_OUT.INDEX,
    TX_OUT.ADDRESS_HAS_SCRIPT,
    ENCODE(TX_OUT.DATA_HASH,'hex') AS DATUM_HASH,
    SCRIPT.ID as script_id,
    TX_OUT.REFERENCE_SCRIPT_ID,
ENCODE(INLINE_DATUM.HASH,'hex') AS INLINE_DATUM_HASH
FROM TX_OUT
INNER JOIN TX ON TX.ID = TX_OUT.TX_ID
LEFT JOIN "script" ON "script"."hash" = "tx_out"."payment_cred"
LEFT JOIN "datum" AS "inline_datum" ON "inline_datum"."id" = 
"tx_out"."inline_datum_id"
WHERE TX.HASH = 
DECODE('8502fe3617b70d12fc65c8c17dab8483f5a7f847e0fba0376fe7abacf4773262','hex')
AND TX_OUT.INDEX = 3;
```

Where I'm getting some info about a specific `UTxO`. The result is this:

```
 tx_hash                                                          | index | address_has_script |                            datum_hash                            | script_id | reference_script_id |                        inline_datum_hash                         
------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 8502fe3617b70d12fc65c8c17dab8483f5a7f847e0fba0376fe7abacf4773262 |     3 | f                  | 93892d0c469bd1228f0e94621d3101e755523e97ea0a837c9b509b1aeb9d8c42 |           |                     | 93892d0c469bd1228f0e94621d3101e755523e97ea0a837c9b509b1aeb9d8c42
```

You can see the `UTxO` doesn't have script `address_has_script = f` and left join to `script` table is null (`LEFT JOIN "script" ON "script"."hash" = "tx_out"."payment_cred"`) resulting on empty column `script_id`. The same goes to column `reference_script_id` .

So we can we can assume no script is involved in this `UTxO` but we can see it has `data_hash` and according to `db-sync` schema doc:

[image]

You can also notice the `UTxO` has inline datum (column `inline_datum_hash` in the query) which value is the same as `data_hash`. I know strictly speaking having `data_hash` doesn't mean it must have a `script` but I just cannot understand this `UTxO`.

Why `data_hash` is the same as `inline_datum_hash`, and what does it means?

Answer (score 0):

`data_hash` is always expected to be the same as the hash of the referenced `inline_datum_hash`. The existence of the latter simply shows that the datum is in fact inlined.

About your other question, you're right that the ledger rules technically allow to create an output that has a datum even if it's not locked by a script. In this case, the output is unspendable.